# useing microsoft power bi with offline maps or with arcgis

Tags: powerbi

i think to start use power bi as an visualization platform of BI,
i use alots of map and i got an esri server on my company, there is an option to connect the power bi desktop to this server?
or to use power bi with offline maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently. This is a good idea to post to our [idea.powerbi.com](https://ideas.powerbi.com) page.

Answer (score 0):

http://esri.com/powerbi

ArcGIS Maps for Power BI is now available.